Deserialization error on the 3rd library class instance in the class (using Lombok annotations)
I want to use a 3rd party (external) class instance in a class but I am getting this error on deserialization:

Cannot construct instance of org.springframework.data.geo.Point (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

here is my class, I use Lombok annotations;
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Circle {
  private double radius;

  @JsonDeserialize(builder = PointBuilder.class)
  private Point center;
  ...
}

The problem is, the 3rd party class has no No arg constructor so that Jackson library can not deserialize it because Jackson library expects no arg constructor and setter methods.
3rd party class is as follows:
public class Point implements Serializable {
    private final double x;
    private final double y;

    @PersistenceConstructor
    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Point(Point point) {
        Assert.notNull(point, "Source point must not be null");
        this.x = point.x;
        this.y = point.y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return this.y;
    }
    ...

}

What should I do to be able to make this running? I added @JsonDeserialize above the property center but it did not work.

This question is similar to: Jackson 3rd Party Class With No Default Constructor. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. I don't think that the use of Lombok is relevant to the fix.

Yes, it is similar but not the same. I want to utilize from Lombok features, if there is any. I already mentioned it in the title. I provided the code and I would like to see code as an answer, not the way of solution differently from the other question.

The fact you are using Lombok is irrelevant here. It simply adds the NoArgsConstructor to Circle in the bytecode rather than you coding in sourcecode.

How can you decide it is irrelevant? It might be utilized in another class maybe. Besides, I shared the code and I want to see code example. Now, you understand?

From @dac1n's answer,
I added a MixIn class
public class PointMixIn {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    @JsonCreator
    public PointMixIn(Point center) {
        this.x = ...
        this.y = ...
    }
}

And I got this error:
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:194) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    ...


I tried with different constructor parameters:
but this time I got different error:
Argument #0 of constructor [constructor for `....Point` (2 args), annotations: {interface com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator=@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator(mode=DEFAULT), interface org.springframework.data.annotation.PersistenceConstructor=@org.springframework.data.annotation.PersistenceConstructor()} has no property name (and is not Injectable): can not use as property-based Creator

Lastly, I added @JsonProperty annotation inside the constructor:
public class PointMixIn {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    @JsonCreator
    public PointMixIn(@JsonProperty("x") double x, @JsonProperty("y") double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

and it worked. Thanks @dac1n.

Np, actually you dont need the private properties there, the mixin just adds annotations. Let the constructor body empty too. Just an empty class with a @JsonCreator will do
